# Google Desktop Gadget to Vista Sidebar Gadget converter

Tags: windows-vista, windows-desktop-gadgets, google-gadget

I have some problem. I need to convert Google Desktop Gadget (**not** iGoogle gadget) to Vista Sidebar Gadget
Do you know any way to do this?
Thanks for any answers

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exact but you can use http://www.3dfreeair.com for download vista sidebar gadget  animation freely . i download and use it . it's an very interesting . i hope you also like it . it's an AIR latest technology .

Answer (score 0):

Most of these widget systems use XML and JavaScript, I believe, so it shouldn't be so hard.

Do you have source for the gadget you're trying to convert? If you don't, you can change the extension of the package from .gg to .zip and upzip it.

Answer (score 0):

Google Desktop uses GD API's mostly. So you need to convert them manually with the API's of Vista Sidebar Gadget ( which uses HTML & JS )